# One query or another depending on the schema the code is in

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below 2 queries:

SELECT * from mytable;
SELECT * from mytable where rownum < 100;

I would like to execute the first one whenever my schema equals 'SCHEMA1' and the second one otherwise. Is there a way to do this without having to rewrite both queries like this:

```
DECLARE
    myschema VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        sys_context('userenv', 'current_schema')
        || 's'
    INTO myschema
    FROM
        dual;

    IF myschema = 'SCHEMA1' THEN
        INSERT INTO myothertable
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                mytable;

    ELSE
        INSERT INTO myothertable
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                mytable
            WHERE
                ROWNUM < 100;

    END IF;

END;
```

I would also like to avoid dynamic PLSQL.

Comment: By the way, you can write `myschema varchar2(50) := sys_context('userenv', 'current_schema') || 's';` and avoid 6 lines of code and an implicit cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it this way:

```
DECLARE
  MYSCHEMA VARCHAR2(128) := SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'current_schema');
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO myothertable
   SELECT * 
     FROM mytable 
    WHERE ROWNUM < CASE WHEN MYSCHEMA = 'SCHEMA1'  THEN 100
                        ELSE ROWNUM + 1
                    END;
END;
/
```